# Magento 2.3.2 Admin Dashboard Page Data Charts Not Displaying

Tags: admin, magento2.3, magento2.3.2, dashboard

Our main Dashboard page is not showing any data such as graphs etc. otherwise, the page renders and works correctly. The page used to work, but I had the theme and 2 extension developers work on the site and now it doesn't work. All developers say it wasn't them.

[Dashboard screenshot here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wifsE_c3FGYuwJ0mgcLMJAS080zCfca_/view?usp=sharing)

Charts are enabled in Stores/configuration/advanced/admin/dashboard -> Enable Charts = Yes.

User has administrator rights.

Inspect Console shows no errors and there are no issues in logs.

I have run the following:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/composer_home/* var/tmp/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* generated/code generated/metadata 

php71 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php71 bin/magento setup:di:compile
php71 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU en_US
php71 bin/magento cache:flush

php71 bin/magento cron:run
```

Has anyone got any idea what might be causing this?
Could it be something simple switched off that I'm not aware of?

We were going live with our site very soon but can't with this issue.

Comment: From your screenshot. it doesn't seem like this is magento default dashboard. Is there any extension which you are using for dashboard reports.

Comment: @nishu I don't have any third party reports installed, but the site won't let me change the dashboard startup page via stores/settings/configuration/advanced/admin/startup page. It keeps going to /mpreports/dashboard. Do you know what mpreports is? Is it a magento admin url?

Comment: Huh, Mageplaza Reports snuck into our system when installing something else from Mageplaza... It doesn't work on our system and leaves the dashboard as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Mageplaza Reports snuck into our system when installing something else from Mageplaza...

Mageplaza Reports over-rides all the dashboard startup pages, and doesn't work on our system and leaves the dashboard as blank. I disabled Mageplaza reports and the dashboard came back.

I will contact Mageplaza to see if they can fix their module.

Normally Mageplaza modules/extensions work well for us.

Comment: great.. good to hear at-least we have found the root cause of the problem.